# Google sign-in button

Tags: javascript, google-plus, google-signin

Research:
https://developers.google.com/+/web/signin/add-button

I haven't been able to use this correctly. I have gotten to the screen several times where it will show me my emails to login. When a press one though, it shows an error. Here is my code:

http://codepen.io/Xavier-Bennett/pen/azQGBx

```
codepen for google button
```

Answer (score 0):

Origin mismatch is normally caused by the Javascript origins not being set correctly in the API project console. You need to make sure that the Javascript origins match the domain from which your requests are coming and to which you are returning the user after sign in.

More details can be found in the developer documentation in the "Create a client ID and client secret" section.

Note: A common mistake here is to add javascript origins for http:// but not https:// (or vice versa). If you want to allow users to access your site from both then you need to list both in the javascript console.

Note : You must include the port number of your server in the javascript origins if a port number appears in the url when users access your site.

**need to set javascript origin in google console api As**

```
    origin=https://example.com
    scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login
    response_type=code token id_token gsession
    access_type=online
    redirect_uri=postmessage
    cookie_policy=single_host_origin
    proxy=oauth2relay554026710
    origin=http://example.com
    state=1995523240|0.4607792083184853
    display=page
    client_id=102180630313.apps.googleusercontent.com
    authuser=0
```

Comment: =
from_login=1
e=3100077
scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login
redirect_uri=postmessage
state=479760096|0.2950279178
origin=http://s.codepen.io
as=4aab4691cc7f5aec
pli=1
request_visible_actions=http://schema.org/AddAction
hl=en
response_type=code token id_token gsession
cookie_policy=single_host_origin
proxy=oauth2relay685548226
include_granted_scopes=true
client_id=1027579471793-dkni5nbkr8upi21trdo80ugbvuto8mkk.apps.googleusercontent.com
authuser=0

This was the error i got